# How to output CodeIgniter validation error messages on SweetAlert with line breaks?

Tags: javascript, alert, codeigniter-3, line-breaks, sweetalert

### **in Controller file:**

This is how I json_encode validation errors to View:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { //if validation does not run
    $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
    echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'errors' => $errors]);
}
```

---

### **in View file:**

```
if (res.errors) {
    var errorMsgs = "";
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name1 ? res.errors.name1 + "<br/>" : ""; //only if have an error msg.
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name2 ? res.errors.name2 + "<br/>" : ""; //only if have an error msg.
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name3 ? res.errors.name3 : ""; //only if have an error msg.

    // SweetAlert
    swal({ 
        text: errorMsgs // error msg
    });
}
```

---

### **Output on SweetAlert:**

This is Name1 field error message.`<br/>`This is Name2 field error message.`<br/>`This is Name3 field error message.

Comment: and issue is..?

Comment: @Alex
Error messages output on SweetAlert with <br/> not with line breaks..

Comment: But you coded with br... What do you expect? :)

Comment: @Alex

Post is edited. I think, it is clear for you now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution myself. :D

just **use "\n" instead of "`<br>`"!**

```
errorMsgs += res.errors.name1 ? res.errors.name1 + "\n" : "";
```

Answer (score 3):

Case https://sweetalert.js.org/  VS https://sweetalert2.github.io/

For : https://sweetalert.js.org/

As documentation says : html is no longer used.

```
https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/
```

Instead use the content object.

```
swal({
  content: "input",
});
```

For : https://sweetalert2.github.io/

if you are using this this `SweetAlert2` plugin from here

```
https://sweetalert2.github.io/
```

You can get your desired result with `html`

```
swal({
        title: "<i>Title</i>", 
        html: 'A custom message.</br> jkldfjkjdklfjlk',

    });
```

using second plugin :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.19.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

you can get with `html`:

```
if (res.errors) {
    var errorMsgs = "";
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name1 ? res.errors.name1 + "<br/>" : ""; //only if have an error msg.
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name2 ? res.errors.name2 + "<br/>" : ""; //only if have an error msg.
    errorMsgs += res.errors.name3 ? res.errors.name3 : ""; //only if have an error msg.

    // SweetAlert
    swal({ 
        html: errorMsgs // error msg
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Very very useful info.